# Generic regression prediction interval

Tags: regression, machine-learning, prediction-interval

Is there a generic way of generating prediction (not confidence) intervals for any machine learning model?

For example, instead of one single point forecast y_hat, could I use the residuals from cross validation and calculate the 25th and 75th percentiles (i.e. Q1 and Q3) and let lower_bound = y_hat + Q1 and upper_bound = y_hat + Q3 ?

It makes sense to me, but I see very little information about this online.

Thanks!